# Submit form using Fetch and receive a response to work with it

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I'm new to coding and front-end development and I got a simple form like this,

```
<form id="form" action="/action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="inputtxt">Select File:</label>
                <input type="file" id="inputtxt" name="file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

I wanted this form to get submitted to a url(In this case, we can just mock it). And once the form is submitted, I wanted to receive a response from the backend. The response is a '.json' and I should be able to work with the response after I receive it.

I used `fetch` to post the form data and used a sample .json file as a url. However I'm receiving an error. It says

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This is how I've written for my `on submit` event listener.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener('submit' ,(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);

  fetch('/backend_response.json',{
    method: 'post',
    body:formData
  }).then((response)=>response.json())
  .then((text)=>console.log(text))
  .catch((error)=>console.error(error))

})
```

Moreover, I can view my request in the developer tools. But no response is showing.
If I used the `get` method without posting any data, I'm receiving the response successfully.

Edit:

1. the error mentioned is showing only when i use POST. It's not showing when i use GET. When I get this error, i dont see any response at all
2. I believe the problem is that I'm giving my sample .json file as my fetch url in the POST method. I think the form should get submitted to a POST API endpoint , so that i can receive a response. However, I dont know to mock an API call just to get this working for now.

Comment: @Bravo No response at all when I use post method in fetch. If I use get method just to get the response without posting any data , then I can view my response.

Comment: this error is showing only when i use POST. It's not showing when i use GET. When I get this error, i dont see any response at all

Comment: Nope not getting any response even if i changed to ```response.text()```. I believe the problem is that I'm giving my sample .json file as my fetch url in the POST method. I think the form should get submitted to a POST API endpoint , so that  i can receive a response. However, I dont know to mock an API call just to get this working for now.

Comment: Yeah, i failed to mention that, ill update it on the question above. Is it possible to receive a response after submission by faking an API call? I got a sample .json file that i need as a response to get this working. But I'm not good at back-end development.